# Size parameter in Plotly R scatter plot with data and value does not work

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data frame like this:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(date = structure(c(16476, 16477, 16524, 16541, 
16595, 16658, 16769, 16804, 16819, 16819, 16828, 16833, 16875
), class = "Date"), y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("date", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I use plotly R to plot a scatter plot like this:

```
plot_ly(df, x = date, y = y, mode = 'markers')
```

The above statement works perfectly fine.

Now, I just want to increase the size of the points in the scatter plot. Trying this messes up the whole plot including the x axis date scale:

```
plot_ly(df, x = date, y = y, mode = 'markers', size = 10)
```

Any idea what is going on? My version is:

```
packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘3.5.5’
```

Comment: try this plot_ly(df, x = date, y = y, mode = 'markers', marker = list(size = 10))

Comment: Wow, that is it. That works. Any idea why the other specification does not work, even though it is documented that way?

Comment: actually, my comment was from the documentation :-)

Comment: Hmmmm...may be I need to look at the 'right' documentation. `?plot_ly` says: `size A variable name or numeric vector to encode the size of markers.`

Comment: Unless, it means I need to supply the size for each marker for as many points as I have.

Answer (score 0):

On the dev github version it works:

```
packageVersion('plotly')
> '4.5.6.9000'

p1 <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~y) %>%
    add_markers()
p2 <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~y) %>%
    add_markers(size = 10)
subplot(p1, p2)
```

[image]